# Hybris ant initialize error : Need to specify class name in environment or system property

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris 5.7 and just recently finished my basic trails.
My license for 30 days expired and I tried to initialize it again using:

```
ant initialize
```

However, when I run this command, I get a BUILD FAILED error message and exception:

```
javax.naming.noinitialcontextexception - need to specify class name in environment or system property.
```

Can anyone help me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace ?

Comment: Adding the full stack trace could be helpful. Please add it if the issue isn't resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

never seen that issue but try deleting your data directory

Answer (score 0):

You can just create new DB and use it as a new trial one.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and even after creating the new DB, I am not able to resolve it. Whenever I try to do an ant initialize, it gives me an error - error creating bean inboundConventionFactory.  Javax.naming.noinitialContextException

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a tenant

```
ant initialize -Dtenant=master
```

This will initailize master tenant